# Ionic cordova android build issue

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4

When I create a new Ionic application and build on Angular I have an error:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: same issue. please let me know if someone know about it

Comment: Can you put `package.json` and `ionic info`?